# How do I create a video, using one background jpg and other smaller changing jpg's in the foreground?

Tags: video, mp3, jpeg, editing

I hope someone can help me, as I've never done this before.

Basically what I want to do is create a video using a 2 hour long dj mix (mp3 file), a compilation. I would like the album cover as the artwork in the background. But I would also like the artwork of the singles to be shown too, but at the same time. So for example, in the bottom right corner there is a single jpg that changes as the track changes in the music. So basically a rotating jpg on top of the bigger still background jpg.

I hope I've made sense lol. I tried Movie Maker but I cannot see a way to add the foreground rotating jpgs :(

Answer (score 0):

Just find yourself a decent video editing tool (Movie Maker is NOT).

You can even use VirtualDub, start [here](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=34)